# Почему у меня размерность на выходе неправильная

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras

Мне нужно на вывод из генератора получать спектрограмму размерностью (?,256,256,3)

Вот код генератора:

```
def generator(gen_df, batch_size):
while True:
    x_batch = []
    y_batch = []
    
    for i in range(batch_size):
        wav1, wav2 = gen_df.sample(1).values[0]

        wave1, sample_rate = torchaudio.load('sample_data/{}.wav'.format(wav1))
        wave2, sample_rate = torchaudio.load('sample_data/{}.wav'.format(wav2))
        
        specgram1 = torchaudio.transforms.Spectrogram()(wave1)
        specgram2 = torchaudio.transforms.Spectrogram()(wave2)

        specgram1 = torch.Size([256,256,3])
        specgram2 = torch.Size([256,256,3])
        
        x_batch += [specgram1]
        y_batch += [specgram2]

    x_batch = np.array(x_batch)
    y_batch = np.array(y_batch) 

    yield x_batch, y_batch
```

Но на выходе:

```
(?, 3)
```

Все записи в .wav c частотой 16000 и длительностью 5 секунд. До `x_batch = np.array(x_batch) y_batch = np.array(y_batch)` размерность спектрограммы (?, 201,401)

**Меня интересует два момента**

1. Почему размерность так искажается, и в чем моя ошибка ?
2. Можно ли сделать ресайз спектрограммы и как вообще это сделать правильно?

Comment: 1. Нужно вообще посмотреть вызовом "по-тупому" на каждом этапе shape, тогда и станет понятнее, почему так получается.

Comment: 2. Любой тензор можно решейпнуть, вопрос только в том, чтобы подобрать правильные размерности.